# Head request through firefox console blocked

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, python-requests, head

In python, if I do

```
import requests
x = requests.head('https://www.google.com')
print(x.headers)
```

This works, and i receive a response. On the other hand, if I open the developer console on a blank tab in Firefox, and do

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.responseType = "json"
xmlhttp.open("HEAD", "https://www.google.com", true)
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
            console.log(xmlhttp.getAllResponseHeaders())
        }
}
xmlhttp.send()
```

I get this error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at https://www.google.com/. (Reason: CORS header
>   ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

The error does not appear if I open the website on Firefox and then send the request through console.
From what I have read about this so far is that firefox respects CORS while the other tools (like postman, or python requests) do not. Firefox even blocks if i try to add this line:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Host", "https://www.google.com");
```

Is there anyway to make this work with Firefox? I need to do some latency measurements by sending head requests through Firefox (cannot use any other method unless there is no way of making this work)

I also tried doing this through ajax in the browser console:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.google.com",
    type:'HEAD',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain:true,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        return false;
    }
})
```

but no luck.

Comment: Try spoofing the user agent in the developer console?

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible considering the developer console is baked into firefox itself. Just so we are clear, I am talking about the console accessible by pressing ctrl + shift + k in firefox